# Set one-key shortcut for paste in Inkscape

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, inkscape, paste

How can I make a one-key shortcut for "paste" only in Inkscape v1.0 (not in any other program). Instead of pressing Ctrl+V I want to press only V (or any other key, I don't care which one) that performs the same action.

I know there are the config xml files in {INKSCAPE INSTALLATION FOLDER}\share\inkscape\keys but I don't know which one and what to change.

The reason I need this is because sometimes I need to paste the same object multiple times (hundreds of times) in a precise pattern, and after a while, my hand gets_tired/hurt.

Comment: Not going to happen.  If you were a win32 programmer.. and wanted to write a really dumb program.. you might.. (I can think of ways how).. otherwise.. not going to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into Edit > Preferences menu; a new window will open. On the left panel go to Interface > Keyboard Shortcuts.

You can change your shortcuts here. In right list, go to Edit and look for the Paste shortcut. Click over the current shortcut ('Ctrl + V') and it will say 'New accelerator...'. Now press V (if that's what you want to use for the shortcut).

*Thanks to @z3z and @inklinea in Inkscape forum.*